# I'm trying to calculate a similarity score, as a percentage, for two sequences of ranked preferences

Tags: similarity, ranking, rank

So I need to find how similar 2 sequences of ranked preferences are and return a percentage.

In the sequences there will be ‘posts’ which are in the form of questions, for now there will only be 4 answers so the ranking will be from 1-4.

Here is what I have so far, I’m sure there’s a better way of doing it. I’ve heard about Spearman’s footrule, could it work?

```
    Postx = the number of posts
    OP = original poster whom we are finding a similarity score against (ground truth)
    U = user taking their quiz
    RankOP = the rank of the original poster 1-4
    RankU = the rank of the user taking the quiz 1-4
    TL, TR, BL, BR = top left option, top right, bottom left, bottom right 
    TotalpostXU = total points of postX by U
    TotalpostXOP = 12 (always 3x4 as OP is always full points)
    PointsU = points scored by user on how similar their rank is 3-0 I.e:
    If OP ranks TL = 1 && U ranks TL = 1
    PointsU = 3 
    If U ranks TL = 2
    PointsU = 2
    If U ranks TL = 3
    PointsU = 1
    If U ranks TL = 4
    PointsU = 0
```

(Notes if OP ranks TL 2, both score 1&3 would score 2 points - but it doesn’t wrap around)

We are comparing against the max score of a post, 3x4 = 12
Max score of quiz is 12 x number of posts
So final calculation will be
(totalPostX/12 (+ totalPostX-1/12) x number of posts) / 100

Example 1

```
    RankOP =
    TL = 1, TR = 3, BL = 4, BR = 2
    Rank U =
    TL = 3, TR = 4, BL = 1, BR = 2
    Points U =
    1, 2, 0, 4 = 7
    7/12 x 100 = 58%
```

Then repeat for x amount of posts

It works but I’m hoping for a better way  or better computation or a formula